# Compiler does not see my element being added into my array

Tags: c, arrays, double

This is part of the code. I keep trying to compile but it keeps giving me this error. Is it something wrong with the assignment statement?

> ass1cpy.c: In function 'player_data':
>   ass1cpy.c:26:46: warning: variable 'score' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>     double average_goals,average_shots,effIndex,score[MAX];

```
int
player_data(void){
    char name[MAX];
    int maxgames,playerId,games,minutes,goals,shots,assists,yellowCards,
    redCards,checker = 0, i = 0;
    double average_goals,average_shots,effIndex,score[MAX];
    scanf("%d",&maxgames);
    while(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d     %s",&playerId,&games,&minutes,&goals,&shots,
        &assists,&yellowCards,&redCards,name) == 9){
    average_goals = goal_average(goals,games);
    average_shots = shots_average(shots,goals);
    effIndex = effIndex_cal(goals,assists,redCards,yellowCards,games,maxgames);
    if(checker == 0){
        printf("Player %d scored %d goals in %d minutes from %d games\nGoals     per"
            " game: %05.2f\nShots per goal: %05.2f\nEffindex:     %05.2f\n",playerId,
            goals,minutes,games,average_goals,average_shots,effIndex);
    }
    checker = 1;
    score[i] = effIndex
    i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

How can I change this so that it can compile?

Comment: looks pretty obvious: "warning: variable 'score' set but not used "

Comment: No, it is just telling you that you don't use `score` for anything.

Comment: Compiler sees you adding the data to the `score` array. Its issue is with your code not using the data that you have added.

Comment: It *does* compile (unless there is something else you aren't telling us). If you want a warning-free compile -- why not *use* score for something?

Comment: `score[i] = effIndex` lacks a `;` and is never subsequently used

Answer (score 2):

It is not an error.  It is a warning.  It is warning you a variable is being assigned to, but never used.  It is warning you about this because this is most likely a problem.